# How make a link to show a list of a subject an jsp?

Tags: java, html

In my jsp project/overview I need to add a link which takes me to review/add and lets the user add the review to the specific project but unfortunately I have problem making that link. Any help is really appreciated :-)

This is the projectController:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping(value = "/project")

public class ProjectController {

@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView addProjectPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/add");
    modelAndView.addObject("project", new Project());
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView addingProject(@ModelAttribute Project project) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/overview");
    Map<String, String> validationResult = validate(project, false);
    String message = "";
    if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
        project.setStatus("Actief");
        projectService.addProject(project);

        message = "Project was successfully added.";
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/overview");
        List<Project> projects = projectService.getProjects();
        modelAndView.addObject("projects", projects);
    } else {
        for (String key : validationResult.keySet()) {
            modelAndView.addObject(key, validationResult.get(key));
        }
        modelAndView.addObject("project", project);
    }

    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/overview")
@Secured({"ROLE_MANAGER"})
public ModelAndView listOfProjects() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/overview");
    List<Project> projects = projectService.getProjects();
    modelAndView.addObject("projects", projects);
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView editProjectPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/edit");
    Project project = projectService.getProject(id);
    modelAndView.addObject("project", project);
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView edditingProject(@ModelAttribute Project project,
        @PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/edit");
    Map<String, String> validationResult = validate(project, true);
    String message = "";
    if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
        projectService.updateProject(project);
        message = "Project was successfully edited.";
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/overview");
        List<Project> proejcts = projectService.getProjects();
        modelAndView.addObject("projects", proejcts);
    } else {
        for (String key : validationResult.keySet()) {
            modelAndView.addObject(key, validationResult.get(key));
        }
        modelAndView.addObject("project", project);
    }
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView deleteProject(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("project/overview");
    projectService.deleteProject(id);
    String message = "Project was successfully deleted.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    List<Project> projects = projectService.getProjects();
    modelAndView.addObject("projects", projects);
    return modelAndView;
}

private Map<String, String> validate(Project project, boolean edit) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespaceOnly(project.getTitle())) {
        result.put("titleError", "Cannot be empty");
    }

    Project tempProject = projectService.getProjectByTitle(project.getTitle());
    if (tempProject != null) {
        if (edit) {
            if (tempProject.getId() != project.getId()) {
                result.put("titleError", "Already taken");
            }
        } else {
            result.put("titleError", "Already used");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
    model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
    model.setViewName("home");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/projectReviews/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView projectReviews(@PathVariable Integer id){

    ModelAndView projectReviewsView = new ModelAndView("project/projectreviewslist");
    Project project = projectService.getProject(id);
    Set<Review> projectReviews = project.getReviews();
    projectReviewsView.addObject("project", project);
    projectReviewsView.addObject("projectReviews", projectReviews);
    return projectReviewsView;  
}
}
```

Here the project/overview where I need to make the list to project/projectreviewslist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<t:masterpage>
<jsp:body>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="main">
            <div class="login" style="width: auto;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Lijst van projecten</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Hier ziet u een lijst van projecten. Hier kunt u ze wijzigen, verwijderen of updaten.</legend>
                            <p>${message}</p>
                            <div class="box">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped"  width="600">
                                    <thead  height="50px">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="5%">ID</th>
                                            <th width="30%">Titel</th>
                                            <th width="30%">Begin datum</th>
                                            <th width="30%">Eind datum</th>
                                            <th width="30%">Status</th>
                                            <th width="5%">Acties</th></tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <c:forEach var="project" items="${projects}">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>${project.id}</td>
                                                <td>${project.title}</td>
                                                <td>${project.startDate}</td>
                                                <td>${project.endDate}</td>
                                                <td>${project.status}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/edit/${project.id}.html">Wijzigen</a><br/>
                                                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/delete/${project.id}.html">Verwijderen</a><br/>
                                                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/review/overview.html">Reviews</a><br/>                                                      
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/add.html">Een nieuwe project toevoegen</a><br/>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div> 
    </jsp:body>
</t:masterpage>
```